# Index out of range error in Telerik reporting

Tags: telerik, arguments, telerik-reporting, server-error

I am getting Server Error in '/' Application.

Exception Details:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource) +67
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +16
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +19
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlElementRenderer.GetEndElement(ProcessingElement startElement) +267
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlElementRenderer.BeginRender(HtmlRenderingContext context) +382
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +17
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ContainerElementRenderer.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +108
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.BaseElementRenderer.RenderToHtml(HtmlRenderingContext context) +26
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlTextBoxRenderer.RenderInternal(ProcessingElement processingElement, HtmlRenderingContext context) +163
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlItemRender.Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.IReportItemRender.Render(ProcessingElement processingElement, RenderingContext context) +92
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.RenderingContext.Render(ReportItemBase item) +50
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.Matrix.RenderInternal(HtmlRenderingContext context) +3645
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.Matrix.Render(HtmlRenderingContext context) +40
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.ReportSectionBaseRenderer.RenderInternal(ProcessingElement processingElement, HtmlRenderingContext context) +69
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlItemRender.Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.IReportItemRender.Render(ProcessingElement processingElement, RenderingContext context) +92
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.RenderingContext.Render(ReportItemBase item) +50
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlPage.RenderReportSections(HtmlWriter bodyWriter) +557
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlPage.RenderBody(HtmlWriter bodyWriter) +320
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter primaryWriter, HtmlRenderingContext renderingContext) +112
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlReport.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer, Int32 startPage, Int32 endPage) +304
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlReport.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +56
   Telerik.Reporting.HtmlRendering.HtmlRenderingExtension.Telerik.Reporting.Processing.IRenderingExtension.Render(Report report, Hashtable renderingContext, Hashtable deviceInfo, CreateStream createStreamCallback, EvaluateHeaderFooterExpressions evalHeaderFooterCallback) +134
   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.Render(IList`1 reports, ExtensionInfo extensionInfo, Hashtable renderingContext, Hashtable deviceInfo, CreateStream createStreamCallback) +352
   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.RenderReport(String format, IReportDocument reportDocument, Hashtable deviceInfo, CreateStream createStreamCallback, String& documentName) +421
   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ServerReport.Render(HttpResponse response, String format, Int32 pageIndex) in c:\Projects\Reporting\FromSC_scrum\@ReportingBuild\Reporting_Build\Net20\Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms\ServerReport.cs:90
   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportPageOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpContext context) in c:\Projects\Reporting\FromSC_scrum\@ReportingBuild\Reporting_Build\Net20\Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms\ReportPageOperation.cs:25
   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Projects\Reporting\FromSC_scrum\@ReportingBuild\Reporting_Build\Net20\Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms\HttpHandler.cs:59
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +705
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
```

I am getting this error in Telerik Report viewer.
Getting this error only for specific criteria not for all the values.

where i am missing something?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I didn't figured out its origin yet, but I suppose it comes from data source binding. When you create new instance on report it creates default controls in InitializeComponent() method (for example, List with 0 rows or TextBox without text). And when you bind data source (for example, List with 3 items) it refer to List (Telerik Reporting control) and try to bind collection with 3 items to control with 0 rows. So in this case you had OutOfRangeException. Something like that, I guess.

UPD: actually, I had resolved my problem yesterday. It was all because I try to bind empty collection as control's data source. I just added default object (with empty properties) to my collection if it contains no elements before binding.

Answer (score 0):

We have been experiencing a very similar issue intermittently. Clearing out the Telerik state database tables seems to resolve it sometimes for us. You can flip `@Condition` to `1` in the script below to execute the delete.

```
DECLARE @Condition AS BIT = 0;
IF @Condition = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE dbo.tr_AppLock;
    DELETE dbo.tr_Object;
    DELETE dbo.tr_Set;
    DELETE dbo.tr_String;
END;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tr_AppLock AS tal;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tr_Object AS tob;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tr_Set AS ts;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tr_String AS ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can preview the report in the Telerik Report Designer.

I was seeing the same error when running code:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

In the report designer I had the error:

> Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all
>   parameters

I corrected the Report Designer error (by adding a default parameter value, see screenshot below) and made no other 'code' changes, this resolved both issues.

Interestingly if I remove the default value the Report Designer error returns but running the report in code remains OK (possibly the report is cached somewhere in a valid state?)

[image]